# MySQL merge fields

Tags: mysql, field

I'm doing the following SELECT query on a MYSQL table (Bibliographie) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Nom_Auteur, nom2, nom3 FROM Bibliographie;
```

This returns :

```
Nom_Auteur : Guyotjeannin Génicot Ourliac Alquier
nom2 : Pycke      Gazzaniga
nom3 : tock  Autre  Castaldo
```

I would like mysql to return all search results in one single list, not 3.

Something like :

```
Auteurs : Guyotjeannin Génicot Ourliac Alquier Pycke Gazzaniga tock Autre Castaldo
```

I tried `INNER JOIN`, `GROUP_CONCAT`, `UNION`, but can't get my head around this....

Comment: Are you doing this outputting with jQuery or just in mysql?

Comment: and where jquery each click append is causing you problems?

Comment: downvoted because the question has nothing to do with the title

Comment: I edited a previous question (that I never posted) and forgot to change the title. Sorry ...

Answer (score 1):

Your title does not make any sense, however this is a possible solution:

Try using CONCAT() in query i.e

```
SELECT CONCAT(Nom_Auteur, nom2, nom3) FROM Bibliographie;
```

Comment: I have changed the title, thanks. CONCAT () isn't what I'm looking for since CONCAT links date on a given row. I use CONCAT to link a first name and a name of an author. What I'm looking to do here is to leave the results as 3 distinct search results but to put them all in one array (and avoid duplicate entries). I hope I'm clear....

Answer (score 0):

I have got it !!

SELECT DISTINCT Nom_Auteur FROM Bibliographie UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT nom2 FROM Bibliographie UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT nom3 FROM Bibliographie ORDER BY Nom_Auteur ;

returns : Nom_Auteur with one long array containing all data fields of Nom_Auteur, nom2 and nom3

Thanks